# How to save GitHub access token in single page application?

Tags: github, oauth, aws-lambda, single-page-application

I created a single page application (SPA), which relies on GitHub API v4.
The API requires an access token to access, so I created an input element to ask users to store their access token.
I want to persist the entered token so that users don't re-input the token after reloading or re-visiting the site, **without building any backend server**.

I tried few things to achieve my purpose:

1. save the token in `localStorage`

It is very easy, but there are security concerns to store secret information in the storage, so I rejected this approach.

2. use [GitHub OAuth App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps) to fetch tokens

It is not suitable because it requires to store `client secret` in my app. Since my app is SPA, the stored secret can be read by any user.

3. use Auth0 to bypass the authentification

At first, it seemed very easy to get GitHub access token, but it requires a backend proxy server to fetch the token as [described here](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/calling-an-external-idp-api?_ga=2.95700188.1328448321.1595445216-223610606.1595445216)

Is it impossible to persist the token without any backend server?
If so, how to persist the token easily? For now, I came up with the below solutions:

1. use AWS Lambda to encrypt the token and save it into cookie

When users input the token, the app send the token to a Lambda function, which encrypt the token and response it into cookie. When users back to my app, the app send cookie to the Lambda function and decrypt the token and send it back to the app.

2. use AWS Lambda as a proxy to communicate with Auth0

As [described here](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/calling-an-external-idp-api?_ga=2.95700188.1328448321.1595445216-223610606.1595445216), Lambda functions can retrieve the GitHub access token via Auth0.
However, I don't want to do this because I don't want to use two external services just to persist the token.